# pg_query like with timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I get 0 results if I query the timestamp column for entries that contain 2017 (or any other year).

The data in w_presse_erscheinung is a "timestamp without timezone"
and looks like this for example: 2017-06-01 00:00:00

I assume there is something wrong with the LIKE part of the query ...

My query looks like this:

```
        $result = pg_query("
        SELECT 
        name, 
        w_presse_link, 
        w_presse_erscheinung, 
        w_presse_quelle, 
        description 

        FROM adempiere.w_presse 
        WHERE isactive ='Y' 
        AND description='PS' AND w_presse_erscheinung LIKE '%2017%'
        ORDER BY w_presse_erscheinung 
        DESC
        ")
```

Comment: `LIKE` is for strings, not for dates or timestamps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on string conversions, you could explicitly extract the year from the timestamp:

```
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM w_presse_erscheinung) = 2017
```

Comment: That does it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use like with a timestamp field like that. Either typecast the timestamp field to varchar then use like or use extract function to match the year from the field.

Comment: Casting in order to use like is a very bad advice